# Getting error: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I need to add class to all the links that have "href=login". And i tried to use this javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(.pageWidth).find('a[href*="/login/"]').addClass('OverlayTrigger');})
```

Unfortunately, i tried so many times and it always getting this error

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token

How can i fix this? What's the problem here?
Thank you!

Comment: missing quotes `$('.pageWidth')`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing quotes in your jQuery selector:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('.pageWidth').find('a[href*="/login/"]').addClass('OverlayTrigger');
} )
```